# Russian text is not showing properly after rythm rendering

Tags: rythm

I have a rythm template which shows error message. Error messages can be any language such as english, spanish, geranium, russian et...

I tried to pass the following Russian text to rythm and the output i see from rythm rendering is all ??????

Это объявление должно содержать информацию о товаре из каталога  Добавьте в это объявление характеристики товара

I don't have any code which encodes or decodes.Its a plain String which is passed to the template. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using utf-8 for your template source code encoding.

Checkout http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor/68d19008800d43ab81a6f09ef29c2426

Comment: Thanks for the example. However,  I didn't understand how utf-8 encoding is being set. Can you please point me to the example where source code encode is happening?

Comment: Hello Green,  I looked into the rythm configuration to see if there is any way to set the encoding to utf-8 and i could not find anything.  Can you please help me on how to set the encoding.

Comment: your file encode is not done by Rythm. Instead you set the encode of your template source file in your editor or ide

Comment: Thats right. I realized it afterwards. I was able to set the encoding in my source file and was able to fix the encoding issue with Russian characters. Thanks for your help